# Can't get CompletableFuture and Spring REST to work together

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, completable-future

I've been trying to make a simple backend for user login.

It works fine if I don't use threads, but when I try to implement multi-threading it breaks for some reason.

For now, I'm just trying to do something as simple as retrieving all users' info from the User table in JSON format. The problem is that the Rest controller returns nothing to Postman even though `dbActions.getAll()` returns the correct List.

There's no error, no exception, nothing. I could really use some help. The parts of my code I'm trying to get to work are below.

Rest controller:

```
@Async
@RequestMapping(value="/view", method =RequestMethod.GET)
public List<User> viewAll() {
    try {
        List<User> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list = dbActions.getAll();
        return list;
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

dbActions service:

```
public List<User> getAll() {
    List<User> results = new ArrayList<>();
    CompletableFuture<Void> future;
    try {
        future = CompletableFuture.runAsync(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                userRepo.findAll().forEach(results::add);
            }
        });
        future.get();
        return results;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return results;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just return the future from the controller method. Make sure  you have @EnableAsync on your main configuration class too.

Comment: This works too. Apparently you need to return a CompletableFuture from methods with @Async annotation. Didn't know this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the `@Async` annotation from your `viewAll()` method

Comment: Most likely viewAll() is now an asynchronous call and the dispatcher does not wait for the method to complete.  Normally for @Async the return type is a Future.  Maybe your intention was to add async annotation to getAll() and get the Future value in viewAll().

Comment: It worked. But I want to use my taskExecutor bean. How can I do it?

Comment: I think your example code does not highlight why an async call would be needed. As mentioned above, if you want a method to be asynchronous, add the @Async to  `viewAll()`

Comment: I just want to add multi-threading to the program. It's not for work or anything (well, it kinda is actually. It might help me find a job in near future.). I'm just trying to learn.